# PHP ForEach - how to jump to another index

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a php foreach loop and would like to make a condition if true to jump to the index +2.
I know about continue that will go to the next, but my goal is to go to the actual_index + 2.

This is because I have a switch case and I need to do something inside.

I know also that this is possible with the for loop by setting manually the `$i`, but for the foreach loop, is it possible ?

Comment: Add your code in question to get better solution.

Comment: `foreach` is explicitly *for __each__ element* in an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that with `foreach()`. Use `for()` instead to control the index yourself

Comment: This answer is only valid if a numerically indexed array is the condition. An associative array would break this

Comment: Not really. I did not meant you cannot access source array indirectly. You can i.e. get keys of your source array first, and then `for()` over that array.

Comment: So two loops instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can best use the `for` loop, this gives you a little bit more control over the loop.

```
$array = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    if ($array[$i]) $i+=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your array to a stack? Looping it with a while clause and whenever you wish to skip 1, 2 or many more just pop or shift off from the array ( pop/shift based on the direction of your initial loop ofcourse ).